# Converting nonlinear matrix inequality into an LMI

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

I need the following inequality to hold;

$$
M+(CK)^{\text{T}}NCK > 0
$$

where

$$
C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}, ~~~ N=N^{\text{T}} > 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}
$$

are known, and

$$
M=M^{\text{T}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, ~~~ K \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}
$$

are unknowns which need to be solved for.

My attempt:

My initial thought is to use Schur's compliment to convert the inequality into an LMI in $M$ and $K$. Note that $N$ is invertible by definition. Thus, it follows that the inequality can be written as.

$$
M+(CK)^{\text{T}}NN^{-1}NCK > 0
$$

The problem is the sign of the second term on the left side of the inequality. Attempting to overcome this, I wrote the following;

$$
M-(-(CK)^{\text{T}}NN^{-1}NCK) > 0
$$

which is equivalent to
$$
M-i(CK)^{\text{T}}NN^{-1}NCKi > 0
$$

where $ i=\sqrt{-1}$

Then, using Schur's compliment I wrote

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
M & i(NCK)^{\text{T}} \\
iNCK & N
\end{bmatrix} > 0
$$

I then attempted to use MATLAB to solve the LMI; however, feasp does not allow for imaginary numbers.

I am stuck and Have been unable to come up with any manipulations that would help me to solve this problem. Any suggestions on how I can convert
$$
M+(CK)^{\text{T}}NCK > 0
$$
into an LMI in $M$ and $K$?

Comment: What is an LMI ? And what does the Matlab routine "feasp" ?

Comment: @Jean LMI = linear matrix inequality

Comment: The feasible region is not convex in the scalar case

Comment: In your original inequality, is the second term not symmetric? If it is, then all of its eigenvalues are real and bounded from below by some $-c<0$. Then $M=cI$ works.

Comment: Why don't you answer me about routine "feasp" ?

Comment: @Jean "feasp" solves systems of LMI's

Comment: There is something wrong with the matrix sizes in the question.

Comment: @JeanMarie Apologies for the delay. Please don't take offense, I have not been able to responded to anyone yet. As Ben Grossmann mentioned, feasp is a function in MATLAB that uses an iterative approach to find a feasible solution to an LMI, or system of LMIs. I do not know precisely what iterative method is used.

Comment: @AVK Thank you for pointing that out. In my original post I had confused the dimensions of the C and K matrices. I have fixed the post to reflect the correct dimensions.